# Using link_to with embedded ruby - rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

can someone kindly please help me with the syntax of the below code.
i am trying to use link_to with embedded ruby but struggling with the right syntax. Any help will be much appreciated

```
<div>You have created <%= link_to '#{<%= current_userr.adverts.count %>}', '#' %> Adverts</div>
```

many thanks

Comment: what is the path you are trying to have current_user.adverts.count link to?

Comment: the path or link is not the challenge. I just kindly want to know the right syntax for writing this ------>'#{<%= current_userr.adverts.count %>}' using the helper link_to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using embedded ruby to access the `link_to` helper, you can accomplish what you're looking for by doing:

```
<div>
  You have created <%= link_to current_user.adverts.count, "#" %> Adverts
</div>
```

This will work as long as your intention is to display the count as you mentioned above. If you wanted to add anything to the link text, like make it bold, then you could use string interpolation:

```
<div>
  You have created <%= link_to "<strong>#{current_user.adverts.count}<strong>".html_safe, "#" %> Adverts
</div>
```